# Extension of type Array with constraints cannot have an inheritance clause - swift 2

Tags: arrays, swift, protocols

In swift 2 I want to extend Array type. I have a `JSONDecodable` protocol. What i want to say to compiler is conform `Array`to protocol `JSONDecodable` if elements of `Array` are also `JSONDecodable`. Here is the code:

```
public protocol JSONDecodable {
    static func createFromJSON(json: [String: AnyObject]) throws -> Self
}

extension Array: JSONDecodable where Element: JSONDecodable {

}
```

But compiler gives the error: "Extension of type Array with constraints cannot have an inheritance clause"

So is there any other way to accomplish this kind of behavior?

Comment: I found this..twitter.com/jadengeller/status/644735717814349824 Any idea what he means by "write a wrapper struct"?

Answer (score 7):

how about little type erasure? It should do the tick

```
protocol JSONDecodable {
    init(json: JSON) throws
}
```

While Swift 3 doesn't allow do like extension

```
extension Array: JSONDecodable where Element: JSONDecodable
```

but its possible to do:

```
extension Array: JSONDecodable {
    init(json: JSON) throws {
        guard let jsonArray = json.array,
            let decodable = Element.self as? JSONDecodable.Type else {
                throw JSONDecodableError.undecodable
        } 

        self = jsonArray.flatMap { json in
            let result: Element? = (try? decodable.init(json: json)) as? Element
            return result
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This should be marked as Answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think [the hint](https://twitter.com/jadengeller/status/644735717814349824) you found on Twitter means something like that:

```
protocol X {
    var xxx: String { get }
}

// This is a wrapper struct
struct XArray: X {

    let array: Array<X>

    var xxx: String {
        return "[\(array.map({ $0.xxx }).joinWithSeparator(", "))]"
    }

}

// Just for this demo
extension String: X {
    var xxx: String {
        return "x\(self)"
    }
}

let xs = XArray(array: ["a", "b", "c"])
print(xs.array) // ["a", "b", "c"]
print(xs.xxx) // [xa, xb, xc]
```